# Transfering Skyrim save from Windows to Linux

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, linux

I'm playing Skyrim on a Windows 10 PC via Steam and I'm considering buying a new Linux PC, so I was wondering if I can transfer my old saved game to that new Linux PC.

I've seen that in Windows to Windows transfers is as simple as to place back the save file in the new save folder (plus downloading back all the mods from workshop and NMM) but maybe in Linux there could be a compatibility issue or maybe Steam thinks I'm using a pirate copy or anything.

In the case it's not possible to keep playing my previous game can I use Steam to play Skyrim (and other games) in this old Windows computer and also install new games in the new Linux computer with Steam?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The [PCGamingWiki article for Skyrim](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Skyrim) says that the game supports Steam Cloud, so your PC should automatically download the save game on your Linux machine.

Comment: I would add the caution this may be more problematic for heavily modded setups. I haven't had the best luck with mods on linux, which is one of the biggest reasons I haven't made the jump.

Comment: @JaredSmith oh thanks for the tip. Do you know if there's a wiki or something where they could tell you which mods are compatible or not? Maybe it's too much of a reach but I guess it's better to be safe than sorry

Comment: @lemon in a post about borderlands 2 transfer they say steam cloud doesn't work cross platform is it only with borderlands 2 or could it be as a general rule?